# AS3 - how to extend this function

Tags: function, actionscript-3, extend

This is first class with "gordz()" function

```
public class Model extends Object implements IModel
   {

     public static function gordz() : void
      {
          newobject = gallas.pop();
      }

}
```

Now i try to override the function but i still want that old code is executed... How can i extend this function correctly?

```
 public class LOL extends Model
   {
       override public static function gordz() : void
       {
         ... //New code + execute old code
       }  

   }
```

Comment: Why is this method static? What is `newobject`? What is `gallas`?

Answer (score -1):

Neither super

> [You cannot use the super statement in a static method.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#super)

nor override

> [You cannot use the override attribute on any of the following:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#override)
>
> [...]
>
> Static methods

can be used in a static method.

Whatever you are trying to do should be accomplished in a different way.